# Displaying Leaderboard using UITableViewController with Firebase backend (Swift 4.1)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to store my backend data. I am trying to display a leaderboard using a `UITableViewController` in Swift.

One of the data source methods include,

```
override func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

which in my case requires me to fetch data from Firebase and store the data in a local array variable e.g `var leaderboardArr = [Int]()`

Problem arises when there is a change to the rankings in the leaderboard. I know Firebase has built-in methods to sort the data and adjust the rank accordingly but how do I manage the local array variable?

`UITableViewController` dataSource method displays the data according to the indices of the local array variable.

How to manipulate the array according to the changes in data from Firebase??

Comment: You want live updates or like pull to refresh kind of feature?

Comment: You would have to retrieve the array list again and reset the variable when the user refreshes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user refreshes (or when you decide the view should refresh) retrieve the leaderboard stats from Firebase again and then reload the table view.

If you're looking to update the data in real time you can add a ChildEventListener. So when the array changes, it activates the listener, and from there you can retrieve the necessary data and reload the view.

Here is some reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener

Comment: That’s useful! Let’s say there is a change of ranking, how should I change the array? The index of the array would matter becoz it affects the position of the datum in the table view. Should I reset the variable and rewrite the variable and then reload the table?

Comment: If your tableView is pulling from the variable, then yes, retrieve and reset the variable and then reload the table view.

Comment: Thanks I think I know what to do now!